# SQL to delete patients who have not had an account since 2000

Tags: sql

I am stuck with this SQL question, i have tried different ways to solve it but i keep getting an error, "SQL to delete patients who have not had an account since 2000."

These are the tables:

```
Patient (PatientID, FamilyName, GivenName, Address, Suburb, State, PostCode)

Doctor (ProviderNo, Name)

Item (ItemNo, Description, Fee)

Account (AccountNo, ProviderNo, PatientID, Date)

AccountLine (AccountNo, ItemNo)
```

The code I wrote is:

```
DELETE PatientID, Item.Date
FROM dtoohey.Patient
WHERE AccountLine.AccountNo = Account.AccountNo
AND Account.PatientID = Patient.PatientID
AND Date <=(TO_DATE('31-DEC-1999','DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags, especially because the code is compatible with neither SQL Server nor MySQL.

Comment: Is there a foreign key to patient in the account table?

Comment: PatientID is the foreign key in the Account table for the patients

Answer (score 4):

I would express this using `not exists`:

```
delete patient p
    where not exists (select 1
                      from account a
                      where a.PatientID = p.PatientID and
                            a.date >= date '2000-01-01'
                     );
```

I've expressed this using Oracle syntax for the date constant.  Most other databases support the ANSI standard YYYY-MM-DD format, so you can just remove the `date` keyword.

Comment: `date '2000-01-01'` **is** the ANSI SQL format for a date literal (including the `date` keyword). It's not Oracle specific

Comment: @PikaJovi - the 1 here is just a placeholder. It could be anything, like PatientID, or 5 or 100. The exists clause is just testing that some record is returned

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I think of it as Oracle specific because that is the only database where it is needed for YYYY-MM-DD formats.  You are right that it is standard and some other databases do actually support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with IN:

```
DELETE *
FROM Patient
WHERE Patient.PatientID IN
(SELECT PatientID
 FROM Account
 WHERE Account.date >= 10-01-2016)
```

Answer (score 0):

DELETE PatientID FROM Patient
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Account WHERE Account.PatientID = Patient.PatientID AND Account.date >= '2000-12-31')